# Send iMacros.app in BackgroundWorker asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013, imacros

I'm trying to open browser and send command to browser using generated `app`.

This script is executed synchronously. How to do it asynchronously?

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
private iMacros.App app = new iMacros.App();

public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     app.iimOpen("-fx"); // open browser
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

**Update:**

```
    BackgroundWorker worker2 = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker2.DoWork += worker2_DoWork;

    private void goToUrlButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         worker2.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void worker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         //using generated application
         app.iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=http://stackoverflow.com/"); // go to stackoverflow.com
    }
```

Comment: Unless iMacros requires running on the main thread somehow, this should work. what problems are you having exactly? is there an exception being thrown? is anything happening at all?

Comment: This script blocks `Form1` until browser will not open. That's the problem. I need to form was available.

Comment: Ok, first off, it isn't a script (just to be nitpicking here, but you're not scripting.) second off, it *is* partially asynchronous.
The problem you're probably experiencing is that the asynchronous part is working on another thread. if you keep the reference to the iMacros app in your main thread, you can't access it from a background thread like you're currently trying without invoking it on the main thread. (which is all useless overhead since it will still be mostly synchronous in the end.)
try calling the `iMacros.app()` constructor *inside* `worker_DoWork`...

Comment: Yes, I can call `iMacros.app()` inside `worker_DoWork` and it will be completely asynchronously. But I need generated value of `app` for access to the browser in the future. Sorry for my english. I will add the addition to my question, so it looks visually.